# Deleting a check-box makes below check-box checked in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, checkbox, meteor

I have a meteor click event handler which is run, when you click on input checkbox.

The call to **"setTaskCompleted"** updates model in django which sets taskCompleted to true. (I am using django to store my data)

**setCustomerTodo(customer):** Gets the todo item for current logged in user.

Everything works but when i click on checkbox it deletes that field from view and mark it as completed in django models. But it makes input just below it checked.

```
"click input[type='checkbox']": function(){
        //changing state task completed 
        this.completed = !this.completed;

        //getting active user
        var customer = Session.get('active_user').player_number 

        var data = {'task_id': this.id,
                    'completed': this.completed };

        //Changing state of task completed
        Meteor.call('setTaskCompleted', data, function(error, result){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            }else{
                setCustomerTodo(customer);
            }
        });
    }
```

**//Helper Function**

```
Checkbox Helper Function:
Template.tasks.helpers({
    data: function(){
        return Session.get('todo');
     }
});
```

**//Template**

```
{{#each data}}
    <tr>
        <td><input class="check-completed" checked="{{completed}} " type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>{{todo}}</td>   
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser is processing the click event and so are you (with your {{completed}}). Try adding `preventDefault()` to the beginning of your event:

```
"click input[type='checkbox']": function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //changing state task completed 
    this.completed = !this.completed;
```

Comment: lol how can i forget to prevent default behaviour....thanks that was quick fix :)